Hayt - Example 3.9 - typo?
Here is example 3.9 (page 53) from Hayt "Engineering Circuit Analysis" (8th edition). 
I believe that the following equation is not correct.
\$ -3 + \frac{v}{5} + \frac{v}{5} = 0\$
It should be
\$ -3 - \frac{v}{5} - \frac{v}{5} = 0\$
Whether we choose current in two resistors to flow down or up.
Can somebody confirm?

Much better to write to the editor with corrections - of course you must make sure you get it correct. I have done this and it got published in the next version which feels good.

This equation is for fig. 3.22B if we assumed a minus sign if the current enters the node (coming into the node). And the plus sign if the current is leaving the node. We will have -I + v/r + v/r = 0A ---> -(-3A) + v/5 + v/5 = 0 ---> 3 + v/5 + v/5 = 0  So this appears to be a typo in a book.


Can somebody confirm?

No, it's fine what they did
When they converted from (a) to (b) they redirected the current arrow and called it -3 amps. They didn't change the polarity of \$v\$ hence the formula is correct for KCL.
Where they chose the resistor polarity, this was just an arbitrary choice and, the correct voltage polarity comes out in the wash (due to current direction) but there's nothing wrong in making an arbitrary decision about voltage polarity at the start as long as you recognize that conventional current flow dictates true voltage polarity.

Ok, here is my application of KCL (looking at b diagram only). Let us assume that all currents are flowing upward everywhere. The current in the resistor with labelled voltage should be = -v/5. Similarly current in the resistor with unlabelled voltage should be = -v/5. If we add all these quantities we end up with my equation. What am I missing?

@user1700890 "Let us assume that all currents are flowing upward everywhere." Doesn't KCL say that the current in a node should equal 0?  So adjust your signs accordingly to achieve that.

@Aaron, As far as I understand we can choose currents directions absolutely arbitrary, it does not violate KCL. My equation states that sum of all currents add up to zero (as per KCL)

Minus 3 amps is flowing upwards. The two other currents flowing upwards are positive.

@Andyaka, Since Ohm's law follow passive sign convention (current arrow points into positive voltage terminal of the element), then we need to have i = -v/5 (for resistor with labelled voltage). How would you state Ohm's law in this case?

You are forgetting the necessary rule that the sum of currents entering a node have to be equal.

@Andyaka, but I wrote −3−v/5−v/5=0. I am summing all currents and setting it equal to zero. In my set up all currents are flowing up. Current of current source is -3, next two currents are -v/5  each as per Ohm's law and chosen current direction and voltage polarity.

The currents through the resistors flows because of the 3 amps flowing into their lower nodes. Just draw current arrows that make logical sense.

@Andyaka, I thought I can set current flow in any direction. It might make equations easier to solve if I choose wisely, but it should not matter.

No, the current entering a node must equal the sum of currents exiting  that node.
